# Angular2 single sign on with Auth0?

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, auth0

I'm trying to use auth0 sso (single sign on ) with angular 2 but it doesn't work ,
and my question it's that angular 2 support sso authentification or  not ?
or is there any other solution ?

Comment: what are you trying and what do you mean by support of sso

Comment: I am trying to create a single sign on solution in my web app with angular 2. I have two app : First i logged in with angularjs 1.x app, then i want to implement a getSSoData in my angular 2 app to get the same token_id genrated by the first app (angular 1.x).

Comment: where are you storing the token. in local storage or its in the browser cookies

Comment: in the local storage for the first app

Comment: first local storage is domain specific in case you dont know. if both are same doaim (sub domain of a man domain) then in angular 2 you can just pick the local storage data with localStorage.getItem(key); and the do what ever you want to do.

Comment: no im in cross origin each app is deployed in different domain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140187/discussion-between-aniruddha-das-and-bilel-kabtni).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Both of your domains are sub domains of a domain as local storage works in same domain (local storage is domain specific)

you can write a service where you can use `localStorage.getItem(key);` to retrive data from local storage and use it in your application

In angularJS use angularJS code to put and get data from the local storage and in angular 2/4 use typescript code to get/put into local storage.